# ASM. Java. Is it possible to count method calls efficiently? Without adding new class members

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

Is it possible to count method calls efficiently? And without adding new class members (static counter variable)?

Answer (score 2):

You could report calls via a static method hook that you provide.  Then simply add an `invokestatic` instruction along with whichever arguments you want to pass.  A naive approach would pass the method name and descriptor, but since this is all happening at runtime, you could avoid the string comparisons on each invocation by registering each method with your instrumentation API when you first scan the class, get back a simple token (an `int` or `long`), and modify each method to pass that token when calling the method which records the calls.

Comment: Thank you! It's better then adding static variable to each class. However in such case i need to store hash map with key - method token and amount of method calls. It's a quite big structure.